# How do I make an effective level 4 Revenant Avenger?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, avenger

I am joining a D&D 4E campaign soon. the DM helped me set up my character. He is an avenger revenant (half-elf/assassin) with isolating oath of enmity. Melee weapon is a challenge seeking scythe +1. His deity is The Raven Queen.

This is my first time playing and the idea is to be a striker of sorts.

Does this combination of avenger revenant fill the role of striker effectively? I will also be joining at level 4.

Comment: Edited, closed. Andrew, we need more character details to answer your question. Specifically, stats, feats, powers, items, and an explanation of what you mean by assassin, and the nominal composition of the rest of the group.

Comment: Optimally, if you could link a copy of your character sheet, that would be greaat.

Comment: Or copy the output of the character builder and paste it into your question. That's a pretty typical way of making characters available for critiques.

Comment: I think we do not need to know the feats, stats and powers to say this is NOT a good enough striker.

Comment: Avengers only reach striker baseline DPR in paragon.

Comment: Revenant is not a great race for Avenger.

Comment: Scythe is a bad weapon for anyone.